# Matlab SVM training for muliclasses dataset

Tags: matlab, svm

I have a question about the SVM MATLAB toolbox 2009b! the question is:

How I can train SVM classifier for classifying multi-classes datasets in MATLAB toolbox 2009b?

I just want to work with MATLAB toolbox, so please answer it if there is a way to implement it. For example, the below code is for classifying two classes datasets:

```
svmtrain( training data,              ...
          labels of training data,    ...
          'Kernel_Function',          ...
          'rbf',                      ...
          'RBF_Sigma',                ...
          sigma value,                ...
          'Method',                   ...
          'LS',                       ...
          'BoxConstraint',            ...
          C                           ...
          );
```

I want to know is there a way for training SVM for multi-classes dataset with writing a code such as above code, or should I write some code for training a SVM for each class versus the other classes?

It means, should I consider **`1`** for the label of the selected class and set the label of the other classes to **`0`**, and train a SVM with above code, and do it for all classes!?

Thanks for your consideration :-)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you working with the SVM that is part of the [Bioinformatics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/) (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ug/bs3tbev-1.html))? Note: those links are to R2011b because access to archived documentation requires logging in to the Mathworks site.

Comment: Yes, I used the SVM which is part of Bioinformatics Toolbox(its functions such as svmtrain(...) and svmclassify(...)). I saw your introduced link, I think this is for two classes datasets. I need a function for training SVM in order to classify a multiclasses dataset!Thanks for your kind consideration David :-)

Comment: This site shld be a good start for you.. http://www.grasshoppernetwork.com/Technical/Share/?q=node/74   Have a look at it...

Answer (score 1):

I have not used SVM in Matlab, so other people can likely provide a more informed response, but I will share what I have learned.

### Matlab Bioinformatics Toolbox SVM

From reading the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ug/bs3tbev-1.html), the SVM in the Bioinformatics Toolbox appears to only support binary classification. As suggested in the question, a binary classifier can, with some effort, be used to classify into multiple classes. There is some discussion on approaches for doing this in the context of SVM [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Multiclass_SVM).

### Alternate options

[LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) does support multi-class classification and comes with a [Matlab interface](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#matlab). You could try installing and using it.

Additionally, while looking into this, I did come across several other Matlab toolboxes with SVM implementations. If LIBSVM is not a good option for you, it may be worth looking around to see if a different SVM implementation fits your needs.

Comment: LIBSVM is an well-know library of svm but I have a problem with installing it!

Comment: Sorry for delay, LIBSVM is an well-know library of svm but I have a problem with installing it! Thanks for your kind help! I must write a code for it! because I study MCS-SVM which is an new optimizer for SVM like PSO-SVM!

Answer (score 1):

If you have MATLAB release R2014b or later you can use the [fitcecoc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcecoc.html) function in the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox to train a multi-class SVM.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the way for solving your problem - is to implement one vs all strategy. One of the SVM's lacks is that it has no direct multiclassification implementation.
But you can implement it through the binary classification.
I didn't see any function for svm multi classification in matlab. But i think it is not hard to implement it by yourself